# Status of stopped process in linux and send an email

Tags: shell

I'm trying to fetch the status of Airflow scheduler which is running as a child process . It runs 16 times with a parent process  .

```
1000     10001 56898 51 13:07 pts/9    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
1000     10002 56898 43 13:07 pts/9    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
1000     10003 56898 43 13:07 pts/9    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
1000     10004 56898 42 13:07 pts/9    00:00:00 /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/airflow scheduler
etc..... running 16 times .
```

It should send email every 30 minutes if the service is stopped . It shouldn't if the process is running .

Just thinking is that possible. if someone acknowledged by replying to the email should stop the email alerts.

```
PPID=$(ps -ef | grep -i 'airflow scheduler' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}') 

if [[ -z ${PPID} ]]; then
    echo " Airflow is not running  >>pp.txt
    mail -s "Airflow process ALERT" abc@xyz.com <pp.txt
```

Comment: Don't grep `ps`. If you want to monitor something, do it right, and teach your operating system's process supervision system (whatever that is -- systemd, upstart, etc) to track it; then any of numerous monitoring tools will be able to work with it out-of-the-box, and you won't get false positives or negatives when something unexpected matches your grep (f/e a user running `vim 'airflow scheduler notes.txt'`).

Comment: As of now we are running it as a process not as systemd service. since it is in production no one will be running any notes or anything . we have manually do it for 66 machines and which is tedious to a restart from different machines as we have hosted in aws which is no connection between one machine to other. COuld you please tel me how can we achieve to send email only when the service is stopped.

Comment: Once again, any of the readily available standard tools (`chef`, `ansible`, etc) will support central start/restart/management of services, while keeping track of the addresses of your AWS instances. And if you use systemd, you can use `OnFailure=` to cause another process to be started if your service stops, or `ExecStartPost=`, or many similar options.

Comment: And no, I'm not available for a 1:1 chat.

Comment: We cannot make use of Ansible because we are using AWS in System manager via google chrome Hence we have only Access,secret key and instance id . With these I cannot access the mentioned tools

Comment: So We are planning to schedule this in cron for all the machines we have .

Comment: Any update/suggestion on this. still struggling to do this

Comment: Once again, you only have this problem because you aren't using systemd. Put your code in a systemd service, tell systemd to restart it when it fails and to trigger an email as an `OnFailure=` event, and you're done.

Comment: In short -- I can't justify assisting someone in using previous bad decisions to justify future bad decisions. If decisions about how to build your technical stack made in the past are holding you back, *fix those decisions* instead of putting time and effort into developing workarounds for their consequences.

Comment: I have created a service since we are using Redhat 6 . created a init service . Can able to start and stop . status isnt working and Without status , How can I check the running status of the service to send email alert .